# Sharekit Facebook Security Required

Tags: ios, facebook, captcha, fbconnect, sharekit

Well I added and finally got Sharekit to work with facebook using FBConnect, but when the user presses share, a new facebook screen pops up with "Security Check Required" and asks the user to type in a captcha. This looks really bad on a phone and is really time consuming when someone wants to quickly post a status.

Has anyone had this issue and resolved it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this only happens when using older methods for signing onto Facebook. The Sharekit tree is full of old and broken versions, so I just implemented it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Is the account you're using a proper test account and / or a real account? The captcha happens pretty frequently for unverified accounts as a spam protection measure, which may be happening for your testing regardless of what link is being shared.

If the account is fine, it could be the content you're sharing being flagged as suspicious, are you asked to provide a captcha when sharing the same content via the facebook website or other APIs?

Comment: I am using my real account and a test account... the real one should be verified since its my actual account. I am just sharing text, I could try changing it to see if thats any better, but this didn't happen when I wasn't using Sharekit.. Do you use sharekit?